# How to connect two current sensors together?

Tags: pic, current-sensor

I have two ACS712 current sensor modules, sensing different things, connected to a PIC 12F683.  I'd like the PIC to do something if either of them senses a current.  Individually, the sensors work fine and the PIC responds correctly.  However, if I connect two of them to the same pin on the PIC, both stop working.  Scoping the combined output, it looks almost flat, almost as if they cancel each other out??

Is there a *simple* way to solve this and have them work together on the same PIC pin?

(Yes, I could put them on different pins, but that would involve using a bigger PIC as I'm already using all the I/O pins on this one, so I'm trying to figure out if there's an easier way to make this work.)

Comment: Those chips have an analog voltage output. I wonder how you could expect this to work at all. You can be lucky if you didn't fry the chips by short-circuiting their outputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear how you ever thought this would work. You haven't provided a link to the module datasheet but if they are analog out then connecting them together would create a problem if they're trying to output different analog voltages.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fzNO67.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. A simple diode arrangement can detect the highest input signal.*

This may be adequate for an analog input but remember that you'll have a voltage drop across the diodes.

It might also work if the analog voltages are high enough to exceed the threshold voltage of the GPIO.

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Current sharing loads with separate sensing combined into one blocks the ability to detect the sharing differential.

But if you also want to regulate shared voltage or total current, these must be sensed separately from differential current.

Also unless these sources have matched impedances and matched voltage within a certain tolerance it will be unstable and resonate without a 10% preload.

If one is a current source e.g. PV or windpower and the other a battery, then you must regulate and sense battery current from any other to regulate CC, CV and cutoff.

Start with design variables and specs for every input and output for the system then break it down for each module or component and repeat and then you have a list of design specs to understand what to do next.

Answer (score 0):

If the two sensors are already connected to separate pins in the PIC, you just have to combine their outputs in software.  There is no need to combine their outputs outside the PIC.

The routine that does something if either sensor detects current can read the two existing inputs without interfereing witn the present routines.